# obtener url de una imagen en Firebase Storage con angular

Tags: angular, firebase, angular8

Estoy tratando de guardar una imagen en Storage de Firebase, y obtener la URL como un string, la imagen se sube y se guarda correctamente, pero no logro obtener la URL para poder usar la imagen en el html.

Mi código del service para subir la imagen es este:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NewBlogModel } from '../models/new-blog.model';
import { finalize, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FileModel } from '../models/file.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewBlogService {
  
  private url = 'https://padeltech-86323-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app';

  private blogs: NewBlogModel[] = [];

  private filePath: any;
  private downloadURL: Observable<string>; 
  
  constructor( private http: HttpClient, private storage: AngularFireStorage) { 

  }
  
  // La version mia
  private uploadImage(blogs: NewBlogModel, image: FileModel) {
    this.filePath = `images/${image.name}`;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(this.filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(this.filePath, image);
    task.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(urlImage => {
            this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
            console.log('Pasa por upload, Url: ', this.downloadURL);
            //this.saveBlogs( blogs );
          });
        })
      ).subscribe();
  }

  // Documentación Angularfire
  uploadImage( image: FileModel) {
    //const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = `images/${image.name}`;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, image);
    //const ref = this.storage.ref('images/floren.png');

    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
          console.log('La URL es: ',this.downloadURL);

          
          //this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL();
          //console.log('La URL es: ',this.downloadURL);
        })
     )
    .subscribe();
  }

  public preAddAndUpdatePost(blogs: NewBlogModel, image: FileModel): void {
    this.uploadImage(blogs, image);
    console.log("Pasa por previsual ");
  }

}
```

He eliminado del código todo lo que no tiene que ver con subir la imagen para que se vea mas claro.

La primera funcion es la mia, la que he creado.

La segunda es un ejemplo adaptado a lo que estoy intentando de la documentación de Angularfire de este enlace.

[Documentación de Angulafire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage)

Por otro lado, en consola al imprimir el consele.log con la url, me pone:

Pasa por upload, Url:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}